# Salesforce : Get ActivityDate associated with an object

Tags: class, date

I am writing a program to fetch the 'ActivityDate' associated with an object on a class. Below is the code that I used. But I am not sure, how to fetch it in a variable.

```
List<Pt__c> partc= [SELECT (SELECT ActivityDate FROM ActivityHistories ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC NULLS LAST, LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Pt__c WHERE Id =: recordId];
    for (Pt__c quoteRecord : ptc) {

        prtcDate = ptc.ActivityDate;

    }
```

But this doesn't seems to work. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

ActivityDate is not a field on `Pt__c`. Your for-loop was off as well. Check out [this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_lists.htm).

```
List<Pt__c> partc= [SELECT (SELECT ActivityDate FROM ActivityHistories ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC NULLS LAST, LastModifiedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Pt__c WHERE Id =: recordId];
    for (Pt__c quoteRecord : partc) {

        prtcDate = quoteRecord.ActivityHistories[0].ActivityDate;

    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you!! But now when I use that code, I receive the following error  . `Error: Compile Error: Invalid foreign key relationship: Pt__c.ActivityHistories at line 14 column 36`

Comment: Try ActivityHistories[0].ActivityDate

Comment: @Gopi Does that ^^ work?